# Почему не работает DI в Unity?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container

Всё делал в точности по [инструкции](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection), но почему то ничего не работает

```
    namespace API.App_Start
    {
        public static class UnityConfig
        {
            public static void Configuration(HttpConfiguration config)
            {
                var container = new UnityContainer();
                RegisterTypes(container);
                config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
            }
            private static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
            {
                container.RegisterType<IContext, QueueDB>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
                container.RegisterType<IQueueRepository, QueueRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
                container.RegisterType<IUserRepository, UserRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
            }
        }
    }
namespace API.Infrastructure
{
    public class UnityResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        protected IUnityContainer container;

        public UnityResolver(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            if (container == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
            }
            this.container = container;
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            try
            {
                return container.Resolve(serviceType);
            }
            catch (ResolutionFailedException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            try
            {
                return container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
            }
            catch (ResolutionFailedException)
            {
                return new List<object>();
            }
        }

        public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
        {
            var child = container.CreateChildContainer();
            return new UnityResolver(child);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            container.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

вот сам контроллер:

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/queue")]
    public class QueueController : ApiController
    {
        private IQueueRepository _queueRepository;

        public QueueController(IQueueRepository queueRepository)
        {
            _queueRepository = queueRepository;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public void CreateQueue(QueueModel model)
        {
            Queue newQueue = model;
            _queueRepository.AddQueue(newQueue);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public bool AddUser(int UserId, int QueueId)
        {
            DataAccessResult result = _queueRepository.AddUserInQueue(
                UserId,
                QueueId
                );

            return result.IsComplate;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Queue> GetQueues()
        {
            return _queueRepository.GetAllQueue();
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        public bool DeleteUser(int UserId, int QueueId)
        {
            DataAccessResult result = _queueRepository.DeleteUserFromQueue(
                UserId,
                QueueId
                );
            return result.IsComplate;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public Queue GetQueue(int queueId)
        {
            DataAccessResult<Queue> result = new DataAccessResult<Queue>();

            return result.Value;
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        public bool Delete(int queueId)
        {
            DataAccessResult result = _queueRepository.DeleteQueue(queueId);
            return result.IsComplate;
        }
    }
```

Его репозиторий:

```
public class QueueRepository : BaseRepository, IQueueRepository
{
    public QueueRepository(IContext context, ILogger logger ) : base(context, logger)
    {

    }

    public DataAccessResult AddUserInQueue(int userId, int queueId)
    {
        DataAccessResult result = new DataAccessResult();
        DataAccessResult<User> userResult = this.GetUserById(userId);
        DataAccessResult<Queue> queueResult = this.GetQueueById(queueId);

        if (!userResult.IsComplate || !queueResult.IsComplate)
        {
            result.IsComplate = false;
            result.Message = string.Format("{0} {1}", userResult.Message, queueResult.Message);

            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            result.IsComplate = true;
        }

        UserState state = new UserState
        {
            Queue = queueResult.Value,
            User = userResult.Value
        };

        _context.States.Add(state);

        if (this.SaveChange())
        {
            _logger.Write(string.Format("Add User (Id:{0}) to Queue (Id{1})", userId, queueId), LogEventLevel.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            result.IsComplate = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
    public ICollection<Queue> GetAllQueue()
    {
        return _context.Queues.ToList();
    }
    public void AddQueue(Queue queue)
    {
        _context.Queues.Add(queue);

        if (this.SaveChange())
        {
            _logger.Write(string.Format("Create new Queue (Id:{0}, Name:{1})", queue.Id, queue.Name), LogEventLevel.Information);
        }
    }
    public DataAccessResult EditQueue(Queue edit)
    {
        DataAccessResult result = new DataAccessResult();

        _context.Update(edit);

        if (this.SaveChange())
        {
            result.IsComplate = true;
            _logger.Write(string.Format("Edited Queue(id:{0})", edit.Id), LogEventLevel.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            result.IsComplate = false;
            result.Message = "Saving error";
        }

        return result;
    }
    public DataAccessResult DeleteQueue(int queueId)
    {
        DataAccessResult<Queue> queueResult = this.GetQueueById(queueId);
        DataAccessResult result = new DataAccessResult();

        if (!queueResult.IsComplate)
        {
            result.IsComplate = false;
            result.Message = result.Message;
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            result.IsComplate = true;
        }

        _context.Delete(queueResult.Value);

        if (this.SaveChange())
        {
            _logger.Write(string.Format("Deleted Queue (Id:{0}, Name:{1})", queueId, queueResult.Value.Name), LogEventLevel.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            result.IsComplate = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
    public DataAccessResult DeleteUserFromQueue(int userId, int queueId)
    {
        DataAccessResult result = new DataAccessResult();

        DataAccessResult<User> userResult = this.GetUserById(userId);
        DataAccessResult<Queue> queueResult = this.GetQueueById(queueId);

        if (!userResult.IsComplate || !queueResult.IsComplate)
        {
            result.IsComplate = false;
            result.Message = string.Format("{0} {1}", userResult.Message, queueResult.Message);

            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            result.IsComplate = true;
        }

        Queue queue = queueResult.Value;
        User user = userResult.Value;

        UserState state = user.States.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Queue.Equals(queue));

        if (state == null)
        {
            result.IsComplate = false;
            result.Message = string.Format("User (FirstName: {0}, SecondName{1} ,Id:{2}) not a member Queue (id: {3})", user.FirstName, user.SecondName, user.Id, queue.Id);

            _logger.Write(result.Message, LogEventLevel.Error);

            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            result.IsComplate = true;

            _context.Delete(state);

            if (this.SaveChange())
            {
                _logger.Write(string.Format("Deleted User(Id:{0}, FirstName:{1}, SecondName:{2}) from Queue(Id:{3})", user.Id, user.FirstName, user.SecondName, queue.Id), LogEventLevel.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                result.IsComplate = false;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

И контекст репозитория:

```
public class QueueDB : DbContext, IContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserState> States { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Queue> Queues { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(u => u.States)
            .WithOptional(s => s.User);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Queue>()
            .HasMany(q => q.States)
            .WithOptional(s => s.Queue);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Queue>()
            .HasRequired(q => q.Admin)
            .WithMany(u => u.Adminstrational);
    }
    public void Delete<T>(T entry) where T : class
    {
        this.Entry(entry).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }

    public void Update<T>(T entry) where T : class
    {
        this.Entry(entry).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

Дело в том что при обращении к этом контроллеру не срабатывает инъекция, и выкидывает ошибку :

```
<Error>
<Message>Произошла ошибка.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Произошла ошибка при попытке создать контроллер типа "QueueController". Убедитесь в том, что контроллер имеет общедоступный конструктор без параметров.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
в System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType) в System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request) в System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
<InnerException>
<Message>Произошла ошибка.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Тип "API.Controllers.QueueController" не содержит конструктор по умолчанию
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.ArgumentException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
в System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type) в System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType) в System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator) в System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
</StackTrace>
</InnerException>
</Error>
```

В проекте Global.asax заменён на Startup.cs

Comment: В ошибке указана причина: в вашем классе нет конструктора без параметров. Видимо нужно его объявить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу ошибаться, но попробуйте зарегистрировать в контейнере реализацию ILogger, т.к без этого не может быть создан экземпляр QueueRepository, а значит и QueueController.